# Hole in CSS border radius rendering in Chrome

Tags: css

Check it out:

[image]

That weird or what?

Here's the CSS:

```
.highlight {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

How do I lose the holes?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py how do I fix it?

Comment: Easy on the down-votes yeah? The weekends just around the corner...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question...

Yes, that is weird but not *that* weird.

In terms of fixing it...

Well that depends on the HTML you have there. Assuming (as i have) that its a `textarea` inside a `div` with rounded corners then you should be able to use `overflow:hidden` to ensure the textarea's corners are clipped. EG:

```css
.highlight {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    background:white;
    overflow:hidden; /* <- try adding this */
    transform:translateY(100%) scale(3); /* <- nothing to do with the solution - just zooming in so you can see the corner */
}
textarea {
    border: none;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight">
    <textarea>
    It not that weird
    </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Good assumption! Thanks